# Glide load Image into a custom view not working

Tags: android-custom-view, android-glide

But the image is still in orginal shape. Any solution? Please look at the codes

```
CircularView circularimage1= (CircularView)findViewById(R.id.customView);
Glide.with(this.getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.picture1)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(new ViewTarget<CircularImageView, GlideDrawable>(circularimage1) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    CircularView myView = this.view;
                    // Set your resource on myView and/or start your animation here.
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResourceReady: "+myView.getBorderWidth() );
                    myView.setImageDrawable(resource.getCurrent());
                    myView.setBorderWidth(2);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResourceReady: "+myView.getBorderWidth() );
                    myView.setBorderColor(R.color.yellow);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {
            //You can pass whatever width/height value you want using  the following function
            cb.onSizeReady(....)
        }
```

You need to override the getSize() function